# monodroid exception while loading assemblies -> Could not load assembly System.Net

Tags: android, .net, mono, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I've got a small assembly with some business-functionality (calling an webservice an reciving some data and give the data back in a list). This assembly was developed and compiled with visual studio.

I took the assembly and referenced this assembly with MonoDevelop and MonoTouch in an iPhone app project. It works perfectly.

Now I made a new project for a Android app in MonoDevelop with MonoDroid. The code compiles perfect. But when I want to deploy the app on the android I get this exception:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Novell/Novell.MonoDroid.Common.targets:
Error: Exception while loading assemblies: 
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly 'System.Net, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e'. 
Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for Android profile?
File name: 'System.Net.dll'
  at Monodroid.Tuner.MonoDroidResolver.Resolve (Mono.Cecil.AssemblyNameReference reference, Mono.Cecil.ReaderParameters parameters) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Monodroid.Tuner.MonoDroidResolver.Resolve (Mono.Cecil.AssemblyNameReference reference) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.AddAssemblyReferences (System.Collections.Generic.List`1 assemblies, Mono.Cecil.AssemblyDefinition assembly) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.AddAssemblyReferences (System.Collections.Generic.List`1 assemblies, Mono.Cecil.AssemblyDefinition assembly) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.Execute () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

As far as I know Mono has the System.Net assembly in the System assembly. I the System assembly is referenced in my project.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

> As far as I know Mono has the System.Net Assembly in the System Assembly.

No. There is a `System.Net` **namespace** inside the System.dll **assembly**.

There is **no** System.Net.dll in MonoTouch and I don't think there's on in Mono for Android either (there was not last time I checked ;-)

There is a System.Net.dll in Silverlight. It contains `WebClient`, `WebRequest`, `WebResponse`... that are, in the *regular* framework (including MonoTouch and Mono for Android) part of System.dll.

The *regular* .NET framework has a System.Net.dll - but it's totally different from the one provided in Silverlight. That's confusing and was a very bad decision IMO.

> I took the assembly and referenced this assembly with MonoDevelop and monotouch in an iPhone app project.

It may be working in MonoTouch when using the **simulator** because the JIT is being used (and missing references will be ignored as long as the code is not needed). However if you try to **link** your code (it's not linked by default) on the simulator **or** try to build for devices then I'm very confident you'll hit a similar error message (i.e. MonoTouch linker and/or AOT compiler will complain about the missing reference).

**In short:** you need to re-compile your source code against MonoTouch and Mono for Android SDK assemblies. That's the only *safe* way to ensure you won't be missing type references (or add assembly references that does not exists).

Comment: There is a System.Net.HttpWebRequest in Mono For Android - I used it. The problem may be the linker. If it is, you can use the AndroidLinkSkip:

http://www.docs.xamarin.com/android/advanced_topics/linking

You can also just try compiling your library as a Mono for Android Class Library and see what errors you get, if any.

Comment: @Matthew You're confusing things: *There is a System.Net.HttpWebRequest in Mono For Android*... of course there is :-) but it's inside the `System.Net` **namespace** of the `System.dll` assembly - IOW not inside the `System.Net.dll` assembly.  The original error is trying to reference the later assembly as it **does not** exists in M4A.

Comment: You got me there ;) What you need to see what you are referencing in the system.net.dll. there doesn't seem to be much. Try compiling your library without referencing the assembly and see what happens.